# PHP sort array by a part of it's element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array:

```
  '491-200' => string '13/03/2014 - Home(08:45  -  17:00)'
  '494-202' => string '12/03/2014 - Restaurant(08:45  -  17:00)'
  '498-200' => string '06/03/2014 - Cinema(08:45  -  17:00)'
  '493-204' => string '05/03/2014 - Shop(08:45  -  17:00)'
  '493-202' => string '26/02/2014 - Home(08:45  -  17:00)'
```

and I need to sort it by a date... I have tried to extract the date from the string using `explode()` , convert it and use `asort`, `ksort`, `arsort`, `krsort`, `usort`, etc but it fails to sort them properly. The `usort` which looked promising sorted it in it's own way which I can't even explain to myself...

```
    function cmp($x, $y)
{
$a = strtotime(explode("-", $x, 2)[0]);
$b = strtotime(explode("-", $y, 2)[0]);


    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Result:

```
      '491-200' => string '13/03/2014 - Home(08:45  -  17:00)'
      '494-202' => string '26/02/2014 - Restaurant(08:45  -  17:00)'
      '498-200' => string '05/03/2014 - Cinema(08:45  -  17:00)'
      '493-204' => string '06/03/2014 - Shop(08:45  -  17:00)'
      '493-202' => string '12/02/2014 - Home(08:45  -  17:00)'
```

Please HELP!

Thanks

Comment: You have to show what you have tried

Comment: `usort` or `uasort` certainly is the solution here. Show us what code you have tried and what the result was.

Comment: Your result is not sorted by date!!!

Comment: No , it's not.... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime` can't magically parse any and all date formats you throw at it; it doesn't know that `xx/xx/xxxx` represents `dd/mm/yyyy`. You'll need to create the timestamp to compare by more explicitly:

```
$a = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', explode(' -', $x, 2)[0])->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Thnks deceze. It fails: Fatal error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on a non object..

Comment: try $a = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', explode(' -', $x, 2)[0]);
    $b = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', explode(' -', $y, 2)[0]);
    if($a->getTimeStamp() > $b->getTimeStamp())....

Comment: Thanks Kiro. I tried that still had an erro. But adding time fixed it: DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s',explode("-", $x, 2)[0].'00:00:00');

Comment: Does it work now? Post the answer if yes. Or @deceze could edit his

Comment: @Dims could it be that you ignored the deliberately place space before the `-`? If yes, please don't add the time, it's unnecessary.